# NSBezierPath stroke not scaled correctly

Tags: swift, core-graphics, nsview

I have what should be a simple subclass of an NSView that draws circular nodes at specified locations.

To render the nodes in my view, I translate the graphics context's origin to the center of the view's frame and scale it such that it spans from -1.25 to 1.25 in the limiting dimension (*the node coordinates are all in the range -1...1*).  I then create for each node an NSBezierPath using the ovalIn: constructor.  Finally, I fill the path with yellow and stroke it with black.

But... While the yellow fill looks ok, the black outline is not being scaled correctly!

**What am I missing?**

Here's the code:

```
  override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)
  {
    let nodeRadius   = CGFloat(0.05)
    let unscaledSpan = CGFloat(2.5)
    
    super.draw(dirtyRect)
    
    NSColor.white.set()
    self.frame.fill()
    
    guard let graph = graph else { return }
    
    let scale = min(bounds.width/unscaledSpan, bounds.height/unscaledSpan)
    
    NSGraphicsContext.current?.saveGraphicsState()
    defer { NSGraphicsContext.current?.restoreGraphicsState() }
    
    let xform = NSAffineTransform()
    xform.translateX( by: 0.5*bounds.width, yBy: 0.5*bounds.height)
    xform.scale(by: scale)
    xform.concat()
    
    for v in graph.vertices
    {
      let r = NSRect(x: v.x-nodeRadius, y: v.y-nodeRadius, width: 2.0*nodeRadius, height: 2.0*nodeRadius)
      let p = NSBezierPath(ovalIn: r)
      NSColor.yellow.set()
      p.fill()
      NSColor.black.set()
      p.stroke()
    }
  }
```

This is what I'm seeing (*shown with two different window sizes*)

[image]
[image]

Clearly, the translation is working fine for both fill and stroke.
But, the scaling is off for stroke.

Thanks for any/all hints/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Doh...  I wasn't considering the effect of scaling on the line width.

Made the following edit and all is well:

```
  ...
  let p = NSBezierPath(ovalIn: r)
  p.lineWidth = CGFloat(0.01)
  NSColor.yellow.set()
  p.fill()
  NSColor.black.set()
  p.stroke()
  ...
```